# what thickness drywall is used for mechanical room ceilings and walls with in a living space

Tags: drywall

I am building a mechanical room in a new house that will be located in the basement. What is the thickness of drywall required for walls and ceilings. The room will be located in a future

Comment: Is there a reason you're finishing your mechanical room to begin with?  Also, what equipment is going in said mechanical room?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Question is incomplete and reliant on local building codes. Your local building commissioner/inspector should be quite happy to provide this information, or at the very least, point you towards the relevant standards that cover these requirements, if any.

Comment: We would need more info on the type of home (single family?) and what is in the mechanical room and the state. But most of the time with single family there is not a requirement. Especially if it is open now.